Como puedo controlar en windows forms de diferentes elementos que tienen un Checkbox
Tengo este "juego" que estoy desarrollando, cuando lo inicio los 4 picturebox se mueven de manera independiente con movimiento aleatorio
(https://i.sstatic.net/QSz95OnZ.png)
lo que intento hacer es pueda escoger entre 0 y 4 checkboxs y luego escoger 1 radiobutton, y que los checkbox pulsados se muevan acorde al radiobutton y los que no estan pulsados que de manera predetermianda actuen como si tuviesen el radiobutton 2 pulsado, creo que con un ejemplo se me entenderia mejor:
Pongamos que pulso el checkbox 1 y 3 y el rdbFacil, pues los picturebox 1 y 3 haran un picturebox.left += random.next(30,60) y los picturebox 2 y 4 haran un random.next(30,50), el problema es que como hay 3 radiobuttons y 4 checkboxs hay muchisimas combinaciones, tengo que hacer cada caso uno a uno o hay alguna manera mas sencilla? No se si me he explicado bien :S
PD: Todo lo demas ya esta programado solo tengo duda con esto
